# AngularJS - Display login dialog for ASP.Net Web API Facebook authentication

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api

I've been using the this [tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/) to authenticate my AngularJS single-page app with Facebook.

Below is **GetExternalLogin** method from the tutorial.  As expected, when a Facebook account has not been previously authentication the **ChallengeResult** return the HTML for the Facebook login dialog (this is the result when I test via Postman, I doesn't even get that far from my AngularJS website).

How do I display the Facebook login dialog HTML in my AngularJS application that has made an API call **GetExternalLogin**?

```
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
    {
        string redirectUri = string.Empty;

        if (error != null)
        {
            return BadRequest(Uri.EscapeDataString(error));
        }

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this); // Returns HTML for Facebook login dialog
        }

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call this endpoint from your browser not postman so the html get rendered correctly and you will be able to enter Facebook credentials in the popup screen, then you will accept the consent screen and obtain external access token and will be returned as url hash fragment.
Hope this answers your question and thanks for for following bitoftech.net :)

Comment: Oh, I need to call the API endpoint using something like `window.open("[ExternalLogin API URL]", "_self")` instead making an `$http` call to the API endpoint.  My bad, thanks.